# Color of background - a graph diseapear

Tags: gnuplot

This script plot two graphs. When I delete the # and colour the background, the graph above disappears. Why? How to colour the background? Thank you

```
set encoding iso_8859_1                                   
set terminal pngcairo size 1137,683 font "Segoe UI,16" enhanced   
set output "emission.png"  
                               
#set object rectangle from screen 0,0 to screen 1,1 behind fillcolor rgb '#F6DEBE' fillstyle solid noborder

Row1 = "set tmargin screen 0.98; set bmargin screen 0.56"   # Top and bottom margins
Row2 = "set tmargin screen 0.56; set bmargin screen 0.14"
Col1 = "set lmargin screen 0.14; set rmargin screen 0.88"   # Left and right margins


set multiplot layout 2,1 rowsfirst 

@Row1; @Col1                           
plot [49900:52600] [-0.01:0.25] 'data' 


@Row2; @Col1
plot [49900:52600] [3:8.2] 'data'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each plot redraws all active objects, so your second plot redraws the "background" rectangle on top of the first plot.  You can fix this by undefining the rectangle after it has been drawn the first time:

```
 set object 1 rectangle from screen 0,0 to screen 1,1 behind fillcolor rgb '#F6DEBE' fillstyle solid noborder
 set multiplot layout 2,1
 plot ....
 unset object 1
 plot ...
 unset multiplot
```

Note that in order to refer to the object later you must give it a number. So `set obj 1 rect ...` and later `unset obj 1`.